# How to get blocked on multiple resources?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, message-queue

I've got the below code that implements a thread-safe message queue.

```
#pragma  once

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template<class ElementType>
class MsgQueue {
public: /** Construction **/
    MsgQueue() = default;

    // Forbid copying and moving
    MsgQueue(const MsgQueue &) = delete;
    MsgQueue(MsgQueue&&) = delete;
    MsgQueue &operator=(const MsgQueue &) = delete;
    MsgQueue &operator=(MsgQueue&&) = delete;

public: /** Methods **/
    void push(const ElementType &element)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(m_lock);
            m_messages.push(element);
        }

        m_notifier.notify_one();
    }

    void push(ElementType &&element)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(m_lock);
            m_messages.push(std::move(element));
        }

        m_notifier.notify_one();
    }

    template<class... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(m_lock);
            m_messages.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        m_notifier.notify_one();
    }

    [[nodiscard]] ElementType &front()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(m_lock);

        if(m_messages.empty()) {
            m_notifier.wait(lock,  [&]{ return !m_messages.empty(); });
        }

        return m_messages.front();
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if(!m_messages.empty()) {
            std::lock_guard lock(m_lock);
            m_messages.pop();
        }
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool empty() const
    {
        return m_messages.empty();
    }

    [[nodiscard]] size_t size() const
    {
        return m_messages.size();
    }

private: /** Members **/
    std::queue<ElementType> m_messages;
    std::condition_variable m_notifier;
    std::mutex m_lock;
};
```

Using a single instance of it to get blocked until a message arrives
is straightforward.

```
MsgQueue<std::variant<int, float, std::string>> msgQueue;
const auto &msg = msgQueue.front();
```

I want to be able to use multiple instances of it and get blocked on any of them at the same time. I mean, I want to implement a method that blocks the calling thread until any of the queues isn't empty. Something like this:

```
template<class... Queues>
void waitMsg(Queues&... queues)
{
    // Block until any queue has a message
}
```

Comment: You have a race condition in `pop`. You should rewrite it to resemble `front`. Also, `empty` and `size` should be private. If you need public accessors, wrap them in a lock.

Comment: Once you have this working to your satisfaction, please consider presenting your work (with its unit tests if you can) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".